# Do any of J. D. Salinger's short stories share locations or characters?

Tags: short-stories, intertextuality, j-d-salinger

J. D. Salinger is a well-known 20th century author, most notably of *Catcher in the Rye*.

He was fairly prolific, writing many stories.  Do any of these stories share the same universe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arguably, all of Salinger's published stories share the same "universe," which is his own.  That said, specific overlap in characters in currently-published works is limited to the stories and novellas that revolve around the [Glass family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_family).  In publication order, they are:

- "A Perfect Day for Bananafish" (1948), starring Seymour Glass and his wife Muriel
- "Uncle Wiggily in Connecticut" (1948), in which Walt Glass is prominently mentioned
- "Down at the Dinghy" (1949), featuring Boo Boo Glass Tannenbaum
- "Franny" (1955), starring Franny Glass
- "Raise High the Roof Beams, Carpenter" (1955), starring Buddy Glass, and featuring many other members of the family, set at Seymour & Muriel's wedding
- "Zooey" (1957), starring Zooey Glass, featuring many other members
- "Seymour: An Introduction" (1959), narrated by Buddy, but revolving around Seymour
- "Hapworth 16, 1924" (1965), which largely consists of a letter written by a 7-year-old Seymour

These are all anthologized and widely available, except the last one, which has never been published outside of the June 19, 1965 issue of *The New Yorker*.  (It's easy to find in a library with a decent periodicals collection, however, and it's available to current subscribers of the magazine online.)

There is also a trio of stories that were published in the *Saturday Evening Post* in 1944 and 1945, all of which have the same main character (Babe Gladwaller); these stories have a "false" overlap with *Catcher in the Rye* in that there's a character named Holden Caulfield, but it's not the same person as the main character of *Catcher*.  None of these stories are currently in print.